# How to obtain an inverse integral transform for $F(q) = \int_0^R \chi(t) \sin qt \, \mathrm{d}t$ provided that $\chi$ is an odd function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, integral-equations, integral-transforms

For an odd function, the sine Fourier transform is defined as
$$
F(q) = \int_0^\infty \chi(t) \sin qt \, \mathrm{d} t \, ,
$$
and the back transform is obtained as
$$
\chi(t) = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty F(q) \sin qt \, \mathrm{d}q \, .
$$

By defining a transform law as

## $$
F_R(q) = \int_0^R \chi_R(t) \sin qt \, \mathrm{d}t \, ,
$$

where $0<R<\infty$, 
I was wondering whether an inverse formulation can be obtained.
I.e. expressing $\chi_R(t)$ in term of $F_R(q)$ via an integral equation and that *for finite* $R$.

Hints and ideas welcome.

Thanks

R

Comment: Doesn't the second equation express $\chi(t)$ in terms of $F(q)$?

Comment: @GFauxPas Yes this is true. However only if $R\to\infty$. I am looking for a similar expression when $R<\infty$.

Comment: @Mattos what do you mean?

Comment: Ah, then your second $F(q)$ is different than your first $F(q)$, perhaps you should differentiate them with a subscript, or a different font, et al.

Comment: @GFauxPas Thanks for your remark. Done.